# How to leave a background job running after dbus logout

Tags: linux, d-bus, citrix

On RHEL 7.4.

We are using Citrix VDA to start a UNIX desktop session for our application.  The session is only the application, so when it closes, the VDA session exits (Citrix XenApp).

The problem is if the application core dumps, we want start a background job to evaluate the core file with gdb, gather & compress cores and log files, and send an email to the support staff with the results.  But we don't want to keep the users' foreground session held this entire time (it can take minutes), so I'm trying to run this as a background job.

But every attempt using nohup, or a customized daemonized c programs (following all the standard daemon standard practices), etc all fail to keep the process running after the X session closes out.  I believe the problem is that the session is built up with dbus-launch, and while I don't fully understand all its inner workings, it seems to be feature that it cleans up everything on its exit; if so, its doing its job.

So how can I keep a job running after logout?

Here is a simple but representative process tree of a session:

```
ps -fju 26811
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
545165    4653  4597  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxlogin -display :320
545165    4669  4653  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxsession.sh
545165    4773     1  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session
545165    4774     1  4774  4774  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
545165    4783     1  4774  4774  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/dconf-service
545165    4818  4669  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxctl
545165    4819  4669  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxclipboard
545165    4821  4669  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:03 /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxaudio
545165    4822  4669  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxlpmngt
545165    4824  4669  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/mutter
545165    4825  4669  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /opt/Citrix/VDA/bin/ctxtwi 16 4824
545165    4871     1  4870  4870  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
545165    4894     1  4774  4774  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/gvfsd
545165    4908     1  4774  4774  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi-bus-launcher
545165    4915  4908  4774  4774  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print
545165    4918     1  4774  4774  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/libexec/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
545165    4935  4653  4597  4597  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 xterm
545165    4973  4935  4973  4973  0 14:37 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
545165    8038     1  8038  8038  0 15:23 ?        00:00:00 ./daemonize
545165    8039  8038  8038  8038  0 15:23 ?        00:00:00 sleep 1200
545165    8052  4973  8052  4973  0 15:23 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -fju 26811
```

So for example I'm trying to keep the daemonize and sleep processes running after logout.  It is it's own session leader, no controlling terminal.  But it still closes down when the dbus-launch process exits.

If I'm on the right track, the env variable

DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-mGwaZ8i3Ni,guid=57f80a3ec05a1036fe8a6e0e5d30ca6c

might be significant, but I've tried unsetting this before daemonizing, but no help.

Any thoughts of what I can do to keep my garbage gathering process running after logout?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: In my example above, xterm is the application, and the daemonize process was launched from it.  But yet, when xterm exits -- causing dbus-launch to exit, daemonize and sleep will quit.

Comment: Further research suggests the culprit is actually systemd, not dbus.  Still don't know the solution yet, but making progress..